# Google переводчик - как на java составить запрос на перевод слова?

Tags: java, google-translate

Есть английское слово. Для него нужно получить перевод через Google переводчик. Например имеем слово "*home*" отправляем запрос - получаем "*дом*".

Вроде нашел примеры на *Google Cloud Translation API Documentation*. И для html запроса и с использованием библиотек, но ни то ни другое не работает, а понять почему не хватает знаний английского.

**Помогите пожалуйста составить правильный запрос или хотя бы подскажите ключевые моменты.**

Далее описание того что пробовал делать:

Вот это делал для Яндекс переводчика. Для Гугла почему то не работает, хотя структура запроса вроде такая же.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetTranslate {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        GetTranslate translate = new GetTranslate();
        String temp = translate.getHTML("home");

        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    public String getHTML(String word) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";
        try {
            url = new URL("https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice/lookup" +
                    "?key=мой_ключ" +
                    "&lang=en-ru" +
                    "&text=" + word);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Еще нашел вот такой шаблон в репозитории Гугла. Но у меня почему-то не хотят подключаться зависимости, ну и код соответственно не работает, возможно именно из-за этого. Импорты отмечены серым цветом.

```
// [START translate_quickstart]
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;

public class QuickstartSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    // The text to translate
    String text = "Hello, world!";

    // Translates some text into Russian
    Translation translation =
        translate.translate(
            text,
            TranslateOption.sourceLanguage("en"),
            TranslateOption.targetLanguage("ru"));


    System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", text);
    System.out.printf("Translation: %s%n", translation.getTranslatedText());
  }
}
// [END translate_quickstart]
```

Программирую на java. Для работы использую Intellij IDEA (комьюнити версия).

**Уточнения:** При отправке такого запроса (пример из документации Гугл)

```
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world&q=My%20name%20is%20Jeff
```

Возвращает ошибку 403. Если отправить его прямо из строки браузера, то даже дает подробности - истек лимит запросов. Для отправки использовал свежесозданный API-ключ.

Так же, установил Google Cloud SDK и прошел авторизацию через сервисный ключ (который скачивается при создании). Вроде написано, что при подобной авторизации использование API-ключа не обязательно. Пробовал делать запрос без ключа - результат такой же.

Comment: Если проблема в `у меня почему-то не хотят подключаться зависимости`, то скиньте pom.xml

Comment: @НикитаГордеев, использовал вот этот pom - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/translate/cloud-client/pom.xml - Он прилагается к примеру [START translate_quickstart] указанному выше. Часть зависимостей выделена красным, пробовал менять версии - не помогает.